# Nexus Repository Manager OSS - High Availability - Clustering (HA-C) or Disaster Recovery

Tags: nexus, devops, high-availability

I have found found that, High Availability Clustering (HA-C) is a feature available in Nexus Repository Manager Pro (NXRM Pro)

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/High+Availability+-+Introduction

I am using **Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.6.2-01 (latest)**.

Is it possible to configure High Availability - Clustering (HA-C) or Disaster Recovery in Nexus Repository Manager OSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time.  It's a Pro (paid) feature.

Comment: Right, this is a paid feature, see also https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/825/6017.